# Use C# to interact with web page and fetch data from every page of JqxGrid component

Tags: c#, html, jqxgrid

I'm not sure if this is feasible, but, on a daily basis, we need to retrieve thousands of records from the government interactive web site at http://www.treasurydirect.gov/instit/annceresult/annceresult_query.htm.  This would involve changing the default columns shown, filtering by Security Type and then paginating through the resulting pages to retrieve all records.

I've used C# to read from government web sites before, but never anything like this.  So I ask you experts, is this even possible and if so, is it advisable?  I could make a case for having a user manually retrieve and concatenate the data for our application to use.

Your opinions and suggestions are both welcome and appreciated.

--Nick

Comment: There are feeds on there for XML or JSON, CSV. Why not get a handle on those?

Comment: Yes, check if they have some kind of Atom feeds

Comment: The feeds only return what's showing inside the grid, much to my chagrin.  Wish there was a button that downloaded the full data set.  Not sure how to check for Atom feeds.  That term is new to me.